# If no activity for X seconds, run function that toggles classname. If activity, stop toggle function and reset inactivity timer

Tags: javascript, toggle, setinterval, clearinterval

After 100 seconds of inactivity, I want to run a function that toggles a classname "show" every 10 seconds.  (The 'show' classname makes a modal appear).

If/when there is user activity, I want to remove the 'show' classname (if it's currently toggled on) and also stop the 10-second toggle cycling function. I want this toggle cycling to run again only after there's been inactivity for 100 seconds.

I can't seem to get the toggle cycling function to stop upon user activity. The toggle cycle just continues to run. Any help would be appreciated! Here's what I have:

```
var el = document.querySelector('#element');
var toggle = function() {
    el.classList.toggle('show');
}

function toggleTimer() {
    var u;
    window.onload = resetTimer;
    window.onmousemove = resetTimer;
    window.onmousedown = resetTimer;
    window.ontouchstart = resetTimer;
    window.onclick = resetTimer;
    window.onkeypress = resetTimer;
    window.addEventListener('scroll', resetTimer, true); 

    function toggleCycle() {
        setInterval(toggle, 10000);
    }

    function resetTimer() {
        clearTimeout(u);
        u = setTimeout(toggleCycle, 100000);
        el.classList.remove('show');
        clearInterval(toggleCycle);
    }
}

toggleTimer();
```

Comment: You don't have a reference to the original interval's cancel method, and therefore you can never actually cancel it. I'm not sure exactly what this code would do, but I imagine that `clearInterval(toggleCycle);` is either silently failing or throwing errors in your console.

Comment: I don't see any errors in my console. Can you guide me on how to create a reference to the original interval's cancel method? Not sure how to do this. I created a codepen to provide a simple demo. [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yQxqoy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use CSS animation added to `.show` instead of handling `setInterval`.
Also your code might be simpler (see the snippet below):

Please note that I reduced times not to have you waiting for 100 secs.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('#element');
var timer = 5000, tick = 1000;
const resetTimer = () => (timer = 5000) && el.classList.remove('show');
  
['load', 'touchstart', 'mousedown', 'mousemove', 'keydown', 'scroll']
.forEach(e => document.addEventListener(e, resetTimer));

setInterval(() => (timer -= tick) || el.classList.add('show'), tick);
```

```css
h1:not(.show) {display: none}

.show {animation: togg 2s linear infinite alternate}

@keyframes togg {
  40% {opacity:1}
  50% {opacity:0}
  100% {opacity:0}
}
```

```html
<h1 id="element">SHOW</h1>
```